# How to get session data on a server?

Tags: jsp, session, localhost, session-state

if i'm a localhost server how to get the session info for clients .
when client's request page I need to know what time they get in , these data i want to get from session related to each client

Comment: I find after searching that : i need to include web.xml file that redirect the url users <code><servlet> <servlet-name>ClientURL</servlet-name> <servlet-class>com.pkg.SessionID</servlet-class> </servlet> <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>ClientURL</servlet-name> <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping><code> to the class file ;and in the class file page i receive the session data and all other details via :<code> HttpSession session =request.getSession(); session.getId(); new Date(session.getCreationTime()); new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime());<code>

Comment: to see date in full details you should import 
 import java.util.Date;

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) for that:

> Interface for receiving notification events about HttpSession lifecycle changes.

Lifecycle changes are for example when a session is created (i.e. one of your clients accessed the page and got a session the first time).